# Simplify the expresion

Tags: radicals

I want to simplify this expression

$ a^{\frac{1}{6}} \sqrt[3]{a} - \frac{a^{\frac{2}{7}}}{\sqrt{a}} $

This has to give me $ \sqrt{a} - \sqrt[21]{a^5} $ , but I don't know how to get to that result

Comment: Do you know how to change the roots to exponents?

Comment: @Paul Yeah, I've tried many ways but it doesn't give me that result, it gives me a strange result

Comment: \begin{align}
a^{1/6}\sqrt[3]{a}-\frac{a^{2/7}}{\sqrt{a}}&=a^{1/6}a^{1/3}-\frac{a^{2/7}}{a^{1/2}}\\
&=a^{1/2}-a^{-3/14}
\end{align}

Comment: @MarioG Yeah, that result is giving to me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your given equation,

$a^{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}}$- $a^{\frac{2}{7}-\frac{1}{2}}$

= $a^{\frac{1}{2}}$ - $a^{-\frac{3}{14}}$

I think there's an error with the question/answer

Comment: The exactly same is giving to me. Thank you! I did it well, but the answer from my book is wrong

Answer (score 0):

$a^{\frac{1}{6}}\sqrt[3]{a}=a^{\frac{1}{6}}a^{\frac{1}{3}}=\sqrt{a}$

$\frac{a^{\frac{2}{7}}}{\sqrt{a}}=\frac{a^\frac{2}{7}}{a^{\frac{1}{2}}}=a^{\frac{2}{7}}a^{-\frac{1}{2}}=a^{-\frac{3}{14}}$

so it is $\sqrt{a}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[14]{a^3}}$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[14]{a^3}}\neq \sqrt[21]{a^5}$